# Workaround for data limit in WordCloud Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I'm trying to display the most common words per category within a WordCloud in PowerBI, however it seems that the row limit for this is pretty small so isn't representative of all the words per category (I can tell because all the largest words within the visual all begin with A). I have over 1 million rows with 100,000-200,000 rows per category, which I appreciate is a lot of data.

I was wondering if there was a way to include all the data per category within a WordCloud, or if I just have to accept that I have too much data and need to take a sample.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI visuals typically do not handle large numbers of records well (exact number depends on visual type). The strength of Power BI is in data aggregation through measures. One workaround I've found for other visuals is to filter the visual to the top n members. This will pre-rank the data, identify the top n members, and plot only those.

Typically report users can only comprehend a limited amount of data anyway, so ask yourself how many words are needed to be a useful visual.

Comment: Thank you! I sampled 10000 rows of the original dataset and that worked pretty well :)

Comment: If this solved your question, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you!